# Mostrar Modal Popup al dar enter en un textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estoy tratando de mostrar una ventana modal al dar enter sobre un `textbox`, tenía el siguiente código para hacerlo pero no me funciona:

```
$("#txt_codigoCat").on("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        $('#popupBusquedaCliente').modal('show');
    }           
});
```

Agrego el código que uso para la ventana modal:

```
     <!-- Modal Escenario-->
<div class="modal fade" id="popupBusquedaCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Busqueda de Familia</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="BusquedaCliente" class="modal-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="stock_bodega">Busqueda por:</label>
            <select class="form-control" style="width: 40%" id="stock_bodega">
              <option>C&oacute;digo</option>
              <option>Nombre</option>
              <option>Estado</option>
            </select>
            <label for="texto_buscar">Texto a Buscar:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="texto_buscar" autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: uppercase">
          </div>

          <div style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="dataTables_scrollBody">
            <table style="width: 100%;" id="busqueda_cliente" class="display nowrap dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Codigo</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  <th>Categoria</th>
                  <th>CatNombre</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      @* Load datatable css *@
      <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> @* Load datatable js *@ @section Scripts{
      <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#busqueda_cliente').DataTable({
            "bSort": false,
            "ajax": {
              "url": '@Url.Action("Todos", "venmanfamilia")',
              "type": "GET",
              "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [{
              "data": "Codigo"
            }, {
              "data": "Nombre"
            }, {
              "data": "Estado"
            }, {
              "data": "Categoria"
            }, {
              "data": "CatNombre"
            }],
            filter: false,
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            language: {
              paginate: {
                first: "Primero",
                previous: "Anterior",
                next: "Siguiente",
                last: "Ultimo"
              }
            }
          });
        });

      </script>
      }
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Seleccionar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Escenario-->
```

Comment: Podrías pulsar f12 y fijarte que error tira en consola por favor? Es muy probable que haya errores en los selectores

Comment: TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function, ese mensaje sale al dar enter.

Comment: @RicardoEspaña debe ser porque Jquery _y/o la librería que intentas usar para tu ventana modal_ no está cargada en la página, te sugiero actualizar tu pregunta proporcionando mas código: ¿qué usas para tu ventana modal?

Comment: ya añadi el codigo de la ventana modal

Comment: Aparentemente estarías usando `Bootstrap` y te estaría faltando incluir el archivo `bootstrap.min.js` o `bootstrap.js`. Te recomiendo que leas la sección [donwload](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download-cdn) de la documentación.

Comment: Sí,como dice @MarcosGallardo algo te debe faltar, a mi me funciona, ejemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/blonfu/uanmy21t/1/

Comment: voy a seguir revisando porque cuando pulso f12 me dice que el error es en esta linea  $('#popupBusquedaCliente').modal('show');

Comment: Para poder usar [`$('#algo').modal('show')`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods), es necesario que incluyas el archivo que te he comentado. Vale la pena mencionar que si es [una versión **custom**](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#plugins), al hacer el *build* hayas chequeado `Modals`

Comment: es correcto me faltaba de incluir el archivo bootstrap.min.js , muchas gracias por su ayuda pude solucionar mi problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si tu código no funciona puede ser que sea problema de los archivos .js que estés utilizando o el orden como agregas las referencias.  Para que tu código funcione, solo necesitas estas tres referencias:

1. Jquery
2. Bootstrap (js)
3. Bootstrap (css)

Prueba con estas referencias:

```
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Es importante que sigas el orden, primero debes poner `jquery.min.js` y despues `bootstrap.min.js`, ya que boostrap depende de jquery.

Otra cosa que debes validar es remover cualquier otra referencia a archivos .js que tengas en tu código, porque pueden estar causando conflictos.

Puedes descargar los archivos localmente y ponerlos en tu proyecto:

[Bootstrap(css)](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css)

[Jquery](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js)

[Bootstrap(js)](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js)

Por último anexo el ejemplo para que lo puedas validar, saludos.

```js
$("#txt_codigoCat").on("keydown", function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        $('#popupBusquedaCliente').modal('show');
    }           
});
```

```html
<link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="txt_codigoCat"/>
<!-- Modal Escenario-->
<div class="modal fade" id="popupBusquedaCliente" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Cerrar</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Busqueda de Familia</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="BusquedaCliente" class="modal-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="stock_bodega">Busqueda por:</label>
            <select class="form-control" style="width: 40%" id="stock_bodega">
              <option>C&oacute;digo</option>
              <option>Nombre</option>
              <option>Estado</option>
            </select>
            <label for="texto_buscar">Texto a Buscar:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="texto_buscar" autocomplete="off" style="text-transform: uppercase">
          </div>

          <div style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="dataTables_scrollBody">
            <table style="width: 100%;" id="busqueda_cliente" class="display nowrap dataTable no-footer" cellspacing="0" width="100">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Codigo</th>
                  <th>Nombre</th>
                  <th>Estado</th>
                  <th>Categoria</th>
                  <th>CatNombre</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      @* Load datatable css *@
      <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" /> @* Load datatable js *@ @section Scripts{
      <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#busqueda_cliente').DataTable({
            "bSort": false,
            "ajax": {
              "url": '@Url.Action("Todos", "venmanfamilia")',
              "type": "GET",
              "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [{
              "data": "Codigo"
            }, {
              "data": "Nombre"
            }, {
              "data": "Estado"
            }, {
              "data": "Categoria"
            }, {
              "data": "CatNombre"
            }],
            filter: false,
            "paging": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            language: {
              paginate: {
                first: "Primero",
                previous: "Anterior",
                next: "Siguiente",
                last: "Ultimo"
              }
            }
          });
        });

      </script>
      }
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Seleccionar</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Escenario-->
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda.